# Show missing dates in sequence in crystal reports and add the data in that date row through report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I want to show missing dates in crystal report column which does not exist in data base in SQL Server.
Pattern is shown below
[In the image I tried to show that 11-12-2019 is missing date in this date want to show labor quota
 and as well its amount and idle amount respectively.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHqAy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Calendar table with one row for each date (if you Google that topic you'll find sample scripts for creating such a table).

Outer join from that table to your transaction table. And look for cases with NULL on the outer side.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there possibility to do it in crystal report. I did this and get desired result but my client want to show this report in group wise so in that case date is existing in database but now result is not showing in any group module because data is not existing for that user at that date and that is occupied in other group module. He wants to show dates in sequence for each user either data exist or not if not exist previous dated data should show in that date.